# Inner border that does not push contents

Tags: css

I'm trying to fill an element with multiple colors using CSS.  Currently, I have this CSS:

```
div.container {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px dotted;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.box {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 6px solid #99FF99;
  border-bottom-color: #FF9966;
  border-right-color: #FF9966;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d0cv4bc8/6/)

Problem is that the contents are not over the border, so it looks like this: [image: Screenshot]

How can I get the contents of `span class="box"` to stay in the middle of the element (i.e. over the colored circle)?

Comment: @j08691 It still pushes to the right: http://jsfiddle.net/d0cv4bc8/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using absolute and relative positions, and making the circle as a pseudo element.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/d0cv4bc8/8/

```
div.container {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px dotted;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.box {
    position: relative;
}
.box::before {
    content: "";
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 6px solid #99FF99;
    border-bottom-color: #FF9966;
    border-right-color: #FF9966;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only way I can get the contents centered vertically and horizontally is to put contents inside a span, moved left and up by half of box's border width.

http://jsfiddle.net/d0cv4bc8/11/

CSS

```
.box .contents {
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: -3px;
    top: -3px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="box"><span class="contents">1</span></span>
</div>
```